# Why it logs all the elements after "if statement" instead of eception of one element?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, if-statement, foreach

I try to build Tic Tac Toe by javascript without looking at someone's code and i want to log all the Elements who has not got url yet but it logs all the elements including the one which has already got the url and why it happens ?

```
const cells = document.querySelectorAll("img");
let boxs = [];
cells.forEach(function (cell) {
  cell.addEventListener("click", manChoice, false);
});
function manChoice() {
  this.src = "Small_uppercase_letter_X.svg.png";

  setTimeout(1000, computerChoice());
}
function computerChoice() {
  for (let cell of cells) {
    if (cell.src != "Small_uppercase_letter_X.svg.png") {
      console.log(cell);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Probably because `cell.src` does not return what you think it would, so go _check_ what that actually contains.

Comment: The cell.src returns url of image "X" it does not have problem it even shows on screen and in inspect element as well

Answer (score 0):

The issue in your code is that the setTimeout function is not being used correctly, and as a result, the computerChoice function is getting called immediately after setting the "X" image in the clicked cell. To fix this, you need to pass a function to setTimeout, like this:

Try this:

```
    const cells = document.querySelectorAll("img");
let boxs = [];
cells.forEach(function (cell) {
  cell.addEventListener("click", manChoice, false);
});
function manChoice() {
  if (this.src !== "Small_uppercase_letter_X.svg.png") {
    this.src = "Small_uppercase_letter_X.svg.png";
    setTimeout(function() {
      computerChoice();
    }, 1000);
  }
}
function computerChoice() {
  const availableCells = Array.from(cells).filter(cell => cell.src !== "Small_uppercase_letter_X.svg.png");
  if (availableCells.length > 0) {
    const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * availableCells.length);
    const chosenCell = availableCells[randomIndex];
    chosenCell.src = "Small_uppercase_letter_O.svg.png";
  }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to wrap this into an anonymous function, you already have a function reference - `computerChoice`. The important parts here are that they had the parameters the wrong way around to begin with, and that they were calling the function, instead of passing the reference.

Comment: I try this but it does not work every click availableCells.length is always 9 and  it shuld decrease every click